# Instalar API en CakePHP

Tags: php, api, formularios, post, cakephp

Este Form es el que quiero hacer en mi web

[image: form]

Tambien necesito esto.

[image: clock]

En la web pone que puedes cargar la libreria siguiendo unos pasos del github, dejo link y lo que he hecho. [Enlace del github con las instrucciones de instalacion de la API](https://github.com/edudip/next-api-client)

Basicamente mi archivo composer.json a quedado de la siguiente forma:

```
 "repositories": [
    {
        "url": "https://github.com/edudip/next-api-client.git",
        "type": "git"       
    }
],
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/",
        "Edudip\\Next\\ApiClient\\": "vendor/edudip/next-api-client/src/Edudip/Next/ApiClient"
```

Luego hice **composer update** como dice las instrucciones que dice el enlace.

Hasta aqui todo bien, ahora no se como hacer los POST para crear el Form, la documentacion que he encontrado es esta.

[Documentacion](https://github.com/edudip/edudip-next-api/blob/master/edudip-next-api-documentation-en.md#register-a-participant-for-a-webinar)
Donde a mi parecer debo de hacerlo con esto:
[image: docu]

Pero no se que hacer.

**Informacion que puede ser relevante: Tengo ya el API Token generado.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que entendí de la documentación tendrías que hacer esto

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.edudip-next.com/api / webinars / [Webinar-Id] / register-participant');
$httpHeaders = [
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Authorization: Bearer API-Token',
];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $httpHeaders);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2');
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($response);
```

supongo que tendrias que agregar el Webinar-Id y los parametros que te indica

Comment: No estoy seguro de si esto sirve con CakePHP